# "ulong == ulong?" evaluated as "ulong == ulong" works correctly

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, nullable, equals-operator

If we use the `==` operator between an expression of `ulong` and an expression of `ulong?`, then the operator overload `bool ulong(ulong left, ulong right)` appears to be used.

[image: Showing use of == operator]

In other words, the operator considers both expressions non-null.

In this sample program, `equal` correctly becomes false, with no exceptions.

```
void Main()
{
    var temp = new Temp(0);
    object temp2 = null;

    var equal = temp.Id == (temp2 as Temp)?.Id; // False :) but how?
}

public class Temp
{
    public ulong Id {get;}

    public Temp(ulong id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }
}
```

1. How can this not throw? There is no conversion from a `ulong?` with value null to a `ulong`. `(ulong)(ulong?)null` throws: "Nullable object must have a value."
2. Does this return the correct value for *every possible value* of `ulong?`, including null? If so, how? The type `ulong?` has one more possible value than `ulong`, so there should be one set of two values that map to the *same* `ulong` value, which would introduce one false positive "true" result.

In theory, I could imagine null being coalesced to `default(ulong)`, but then the result in my example above would be true, which would be an incorrect answer. And as we can see, the compiler does not make that mistake - it answers correctly.

Comment: `(temp2 as Temp)?.Id` returns a `ulong?` which can be used as a parameter to [C# lifted operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#operators)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#lifted-operators):

> ***Lifted operators*** permit predefined and user-defined operators that operate on non-nullable value types to also be used with nullable forms of those types. Lifted operators are constructed from predefined and user-defined operators that meet certain requirements, as described in the following:
>
> ...
>
> - For the equality operators
>
>   ```
>   ==  !=
>   ```
>
> a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is `bool`. The lifted form is constructed by adding a single `?` modifier to each operand type. The lifted operator considers two null values equal, and a null value unequal to any non-null value. If both operands are non-null, the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying operator to produce the `bool` result.

You're not using the operator:

```
bool ==(ulong left, ulong right)
```

You're using the lifted operator:

```
bool ==(ulong? left, ulong? right)
```

This operator takes two `ulong?` parameters, and returns true if both are null, or if both are non-null and have the same value.

---

You're probably looking at Visual Studio, which does show you something confusing in this case:

[image: Visual Studio screenshot]

Don't be confused by this -- as @mjwills pointed out in the comments, [this is a known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/21494).

---

If you write this:

```
public bool M(ulong a, ulong? b) {
    return a == b;
}
```

Then the compiler produces the following code:

```
public bool M(ulong a, ulong? b)
{
    ulong? num = b;
    return (a == num.GetValueOrDefault()) & num.HasValue;
}
```

`num.GetValueOrDefault()` returns `0` if `b` is `null`, otherwise the value of `b`. So `M` returns `true` if and only if `b` is not null, and has the same value as `a`.

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYYBGA9uQDboCyAFAK5XkB2A5ugIYA06zbdgH50pAJT5CxaVADs3dAF5FogNxSiAX2SagA==)

Comment: That explains it all. I was unaware of lifted operators. Thank you for the elaborate answer!

Answer (score 7):

> If we use the == operator between an expression of ulong and an
>   expression of ulong?, then the operator overload bool ulong(ulong
>   left, ulong right) is used.

A large part of the issue is that Visual Studio's intellisense incorrectly shows `ulong`'s `==` operator being used (if you hover over `==`).

This is a bug, as per https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/21494 . It is not *actually* using that operator.

Since all of your other questions are based on that faulty premise, realising the existence of that bug makes the other issues largely disappear.